# Which Gedmatch admixture calculators are most useful for an individual of predominately African American descent?

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, gedmatch.com

According to my Ancestry DNA autosomal test results, my admixture is 70% Sub-Saharan African, 25% European and 4% Native American. Which Gedmatch admixture calculators might I find particularly useful for ferreting out further detail on such a combination? I'm familiar with the limitations of autosomal interpretation in general and Gedmatch calculators in particular. I'm not seeking exact answers through the calculators, but I know that some are more skewed toward certain populations than others.

Answer (score 4):

For your African ancestry, accounting for European:

- in project Dodecad, try calculator Dodecad V3
- in project Ethiohelix, try EthioHelix K10 + French
- in project GedrosiaDNA, try calculator Gedrosia K3

For your Native American ancestry,

- in project Eurogenes, try comparing calculator Eurogenes K12 with K12b
- in project HarrapaWorld, try its one calculator

For more information, History Chick posted [A Gedmatch Admixture Guide](http://genealogical-musings.blogspot.ca/2017/04/finally-gedmatch-admixture-guide.html) that gives a description of each of the calculators.